# I want to write in csv file and it only write the last value (I print the value and it work but in csv not)

Tags: python

```
for box in boxes:
    (x, y, w, h) = [int(v) for v in box]
    a = x + w
    b = y + h
    cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (a, b), (0, 255, 0), 2)
    with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w', newline='') as employee_file:
        employee_writer = csv.writer(employee_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='"',
                                     quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)

        employee_writer.writerow(str[x,a])
```

My code must write all the values in x, y, b but it writes only one line, the last.

Comment: Have you tried putting `with open('employee_file.csv', mode='w', newline='') as employee_file:` first, before the for loop? So you're not opening the file within the for loop each time?

Comment: The `employee_writer.writerow(str[x,a])` line must be within the `for` loop, basically, the `for` loop must be within the context manager.

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to use **append** mode for writing to your file in a for loop. Otherwise, you will end up with only the last x,y,b values in your data.

```
with open('employee_file.csv', mode='a', newline='')
```

The line above will solve your issue. Use mode **'a'**. You're opening the file in **write mode**. Write mode over-writes the previous content in the file. Therefore, every time your code opens the file, it clears the data in it.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem here. The `writerow` is being executed just once, hence there is one single entry in the file. The `writerow` must be a part of the `for` loop for it to write all the entries. `mode='a'` is useful if one is appending data to an already existing file.

Comment: Thank you. It work. I change it to "a" instead of "w"

Comment: I would disagree with you on that. You could either bring the for inside the open file loop in order to use the write mode. If you're opening a file in write mode for every iteration of the for loop, the data keeps getting overwritten. Hence, the append mode needs to be used in order to avoid the over writing. @CavinDsouza

Comment: Glad I could help @TiaNomena